# Combining lists that repeat values

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have this List:

```
result = [['A', 100], ['A', 200], ['A', 300], ['A', 100, 'WERKS'], [A, 200, 'MATNR'], [A, 300, 'RESNR']]
```

I've been trying to remove lists that are duplicates of others. So, [A, 100] is a small duplicate of [A, 100, WERKS]. Therefore [A,100] would be removed. If the list can be found within another list it will be removed. Is there a way to do this in python?

new list should be:

```
result2 = [['A',100, 'WERKS'], ['A', 200, 'MATNR'], [A, 300, 'RESNR']]
```

Comment: Should A / WERKS / MATNR / etc. be in double quotes (i.e. are those strings)?

Comment: Python doesn't have a built-in function for matching sublists like this, you'll need to write it yourself.

Comment: Does order matter? In particular -- if I had `[100, "A"]` in the input list, would that be removed?

Comment: yes, @BrokenBenchmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this using set comparisons and a list comprehension. If any sublist converted to set is a strict subset of another, then don't keep it.

```
sets = list(map(set, result))
out = [l for l in result if not any(set(l)<s for s in sets)]
```

Be aware that the worst complexity is O(n**2)!

output:

```
[['A', 100, 'WERKS'], ['A', 200, 'MATNR'], ['A', 300, 'RESNR']]
```